# android - nothing happening when navigation drawer icon is tapped

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I followed a tutorial to set a navigation drawer and it worked in my main activity. Now I tried to move it to almost every other activity creating a BaseActivity, but after making changes, navigation drawer icon is inactive, and does nothing when pressed.

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //Hide the semy cirle at th bottom of the action bar when the user slides to the top
        mWebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        //mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                view.stopLoading();  // may not be needed
                switch (Locale.getDefault().toString()) {
                    case "es_ES":
                        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/errorPage.forMainActivity.es_ES.HTML");
                        break;
                    default:
                        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/errorPage.forMainActivity.en_US.HTML");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //sendRegistrationIdToBackend();
                //getCookies();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.contains("CommentsPopUp")) {
                    Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CommentsPopUpActivity.class);
                    startActivity(a);
                } else if (url.contains("postPopUp")) {
                    Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostPopUpActivity.class);
                    startActivity(b);
                } else if (url.contains("ProfilePicPopUp")) {
                    Intent c = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfilePicPopUpActivity.class);
                    startActivity(c);
                } else if (url.contains("PostPicPopUp")) {
                    Intent c = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostPicsPopUpActivity.class);
                    startActivity(c);
                } else if (url.contains("reloadIndex")) {
                    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.6/udazz/2.0/2.1/android/2.0/");
                } else if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().length() == 0) {
                    return false;
                } else {                // Otherwise, give the default behavior (open in browser)
                    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.6/udazz/2.0/2.1/android/2.0/");

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
       // mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void getCookies() {
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie("http://192.168.0.6/");
        //Log.i("UdazzT", cookies);
    }
}
```

BaseActivity code:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mDrawerList;
    RelativeLayout mDrawerPane;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    ArrayList<NavItem> mNavItems = new ArrayList<NavItem>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.myPosts), "", R.mipmap.ic_action_home));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.myFriends), "", R.mipmap.ic_action_about));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.findFriends), "", R.mipmap.ic_action_about));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.profileInfo), "", R.mipmap.ic_action_about));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.profilePic), "", R.mipmap.ic_action_about));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.notifications), "", R.mipmap.ic_action_settings));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.contact), "", R.mipmap.ic_action_settings));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.logOut), "", R.mipmap.ic_action_about));

        // DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        // Populate the Navigtion Drawer with options
        mDrawerPane = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerPane);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
        DrawerListAdapter adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this, mNavItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Drawer Item click listeners
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItemFromDrawer(position);
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_base, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle
        // If it returns true, then it has handled
        // the nav drawer indicator touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)){ //replace this with actual function which returns if the drawer is open
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);     // replace this with actual function which closes drawer
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    /*
    * Called when a particular item from the navigation drawer
    * is selected.
    * */
    private void selectItemFromDrawer(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent a = new Intent(this, MyPostsActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent b = new Intent(this, MyFriendsActivity.class);
                startActivity(b);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent c = new Intent(this, FindFriendsActivity.class);
                startActivity(c);
                break;
            case 3:
                Intent d = new Intent(this, MyProfileInfoActivity.class);
                startActivity(d);
                break;
            case 5:
                Intent f = new Intent(this, MyNotificationsActivity.class);
                startActivity(f);
                break;
            case 6:
                Intent g = new Intent(this, ContactActivity.class);
                startActivity(g);
                break;
            case 7:
                //mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.6/udazz/2.0/2.1/android/2.0/signOut.php");
                break;
        }

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        //setTitle(mNavItems.get(position).mTitle);

        // Close the drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerPane);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
class NavItem {
    String mTitle;
    String mSubtitle;
    int mIcon;

    public NavItem(String title, String subtitle, int icon) {
        mTitle = title;
        mSubtitle = subtitle;
        mIcon = icon;
    }
}
class DrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<NavItem> mNavItems;

    public DrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavItem> navItems) {
        mContext = context;
        mNavItems = navItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNavItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mNavItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item, null);
        }
        else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView subtitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        titleView.setText(mNavItems.get(position).mTitle);
        subtitleView.setText(mNavItems.get(position).mSubtitle);
        iconView.setImageResource(mNavItems.get(position).mIcon);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: if i am not wrong, are you trying to say you are not getting icon to open navigation drawer? .. which is known as hamburger icon? do you mean that?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: alright i have posted solution! try that.

Answer (score 1):

i have given this answer.
refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30490289/3498931  and 
in your case, implement **syncState()** method after the setting the listener to mDrawerLayout.

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
```

after this statement, use the code i given in link. also you have duplication of code, remove the code from class which is not applicable. both way it is possible, but keep one only whichever works to avoid further conflict, unreadability or confustion.