# Home button not showing up in navigation drawer android

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I'm using `navigation drawer` for a project, everything is working fine but one small problem, I always that `arrow` displayed not `home` button.
I tried everything found in the documentations, forums and here nothing is actually working.

What I tried so far:

```
mDrawerToggle.syncState(); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




@Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.getmDrawerToggle().syncState();
    }

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();


actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
```

NavigationDrawerFragment:

```
// Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you mean you see an arrow?

Comment: yes the back arrow all the time

Comment: What happens when you click on the back arrow?

Comment: it shows up the drawer but the normal behavior it has to show the "humberger" icon too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30490289/3498931 look at this answer i gave.. this should solve your problem.. i could post the answer here but i don't want to get the reputation for the same knowledge i have.. plus.. there are lots of answers on this topic....you just needed to search a little more.. if the link's answer doesn't work then let me know.. thanks

Comment: Can you show some more code from your Activity? Like how you initialize the drawer and implement the drawerListener.

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati I already tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: then post the code..detailed..

Comment: your problem is solved or not? let me know

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but it's different from the actual navigation drawer where there is no drawer and no option menu

Answer (score 0):

i have been busy making a simple app with navigation drawer..don't use template there are deprecated methods..
This is completely working.. i created this example.. try this..

your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   Toolbar toolbar;


  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    Profile profile = (Profile) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.profileFragmentInMain);
    profile.setUp((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer),toolbar);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is your Fragment..

```
public class Profile extends Fragment {

ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
    return view;
}

public void setUp(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {

    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);


    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run(){

            drawerToggle.syncState();
        }

    });
}
}
```

this is all in classes..

now xml layouts..

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profileFragmentInMain"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/profile"
    android:name="com.example.ajay.myapplication.Profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/profile"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

your profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar">

</LinearLayout>
```

your toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/app_toolbar" />
```

previews :

open the drawer
[image]

closed drawer
[image]

Additional Info : I have added toolbar which is Material Design implemetation of ActionBar. Its latest way to create Actionbar. You can use that. just in case, select Theme with **NoActionbBar** in your styles.xml file.

Comment: both are implemented automatically by Android studio template

Comment: i updated my answer.. don't use template.. it has mostly deprecated things.. this is simple example of drawerlayout  with toggle working.. i have tested and run it.. completely working..

Comment: you just need to copy and paste it.. hope you will learn and try to understand.. it..

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the solution. I just took of this `R.drawable.ic_drawer` from:

```
 drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.open, R.string.close);
```

And it worked like a charm.

Comment: Your effort was appreciated and I mentioned but it wasn't what I was looking for. This comment is useless.